# isolated network creation for iot device testing

Tags: networking, router, iot

I state that I am not an expert in networks, what I want to obtain is a LAN physically separated from my home LAN to be able to test my iot devices, but I want my pc connected to the isolated network to be able to connect to my NAS which is located on the home LAN.
but now I just tried to connect a second openwrt router installed above to my modem / router but without results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely what you want (isolated LAN but accessible) does not really exist as you state.

Some Netgear and TP-Link managed switches support VLANs.  A VLAN is isolated so that getting to it from your Home Network or to your Home Network from it may not be possible or be very tricky depending on the setup of the VLAN.

Another and easier way is to add a Router and connect the WAN port of your router to a LAN port on your Home Network. This puts the Routers network on a completely different subnet, but you can often access devices on the other subnet by IP address.

So true isolation will keep devices separate but not allow NAS access across the  isolation.

Different subnets are less secure (but still offer security) and do allow access across the subnets.